# R list all distinct values for each value of another variable

Tags: r

I would like to list all distinct values associated with values of another variable. For instance:

```
nums <- rep(1:3,5)
nums2 <- 142:156
numbers <- data.frame(sort(nums),nums2)

         nums nums2
1           1   142
2           1   143
3           1   144
4           1   145
5           1   146
6           2   147
7           2   148
8           2   149
9           2   150
10          2   151
11          3   152
12          3   153
13          3   154
14          3   155
15          3   156
```

Now I want to figure out how to list all unique values of `nums2` for each unique value of `nums` such that i can get a list like this:

```
         nums values
1           1   142,143,144,145,146
2           2   147,148,149,150,151
3           3   152,153,154,155,156
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` together with `paste` for this:

```
aggregate(cbind(values=nums2) ~ nums, numbers, paste, collapse=",")
  nums              values
1    1 142,145,148,151,154
2    2 143,146,149,152,155
3    3 144,147,150,153,156
```

Comment: thanks @RichScriven result looks better that way (even though cbind removes some readability)

Answer (score 1):

```
setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(split(numbers, numbers$sort.nums.),
                      function(a) c(a$sort.nums[1], paste(a$nums2, collapse = ", "))))),
                      nm = c("nums","values"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr` this would look like:

```
numbers %>% group_by(sort.nums.) %>% summarise( values= paste(nums2,collapse=",") )
```

Comment: i don't if it's incorrect usage or what, but dplyr's `group_by` isn't operating like i'd like it (e.g. stata's `bysort`). thanks for your contribution, but it created a 1X1 frame, all values listed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(numbers))[, .(values = toString(nums2)), by = nums]
#   nums                  values
#1:    1 142, 143, 144, 145, 146
#2:    2 147, 148, 149, 150, 151
#3:    3 152, 153, 154, 155, 156
```